# Accidentally uninstalled snap, can't reinstall because i have no network

Tags: networking, software-installation

I'm running 20.04, I uninstalled an old python version and it apparently also uninstalled snapd. After rebooting I have no network connection, because i guess netplan is installed/run by snap, so now i'm unable to reinstall snapd. Is there a fix or do i just need to start from scratch?

Comment: Don't mess with the default Python version in Ubuntu, because that will remove many important system components. You can fresh install the Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, which will be supported until 2027.

Comment: Well that sucks, thanks

Comment: Also, apt tell you exactly what it is going to remove and gives you a clear opportunity to cancel. Always read that list before agreeing to any removals.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you should probably reinstall. Snapd and netplan have nothing to do with each other. You probably removed the system version of Python, which removes A LOT of important packages.